# Apache Beam / GCP Dataflow -- Python sdk harness failed: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to send custom metrics to datadog using a DoFn but the python sdk test harness is failing with an error that I don't know how to interpret:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker_main.py", line 181, in main
    sdk_harness.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 256, in run
    getattr(self, SdkHarness.REQUEST_METHOD_PREFIX + request_type)(
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
```

**Where are `SdkHarness.REQUEST_METHOD_PREFIX` and `request_type` defined and what is the sdk harness accomplishing? Can I turn it off?**

I'm running the streaming pipeline as a flex template in gcp dataflow, using the python requests module for POST calls

---

- apache-beam[gcp]==2.49.0
- gcr.io/dataflow-templates-base/python310-template-launcher-base

---

update

When I comment out the windowinto line the error goes away but the pipeline still doesn't function as expected -- which might be an issue with my custom DoFn

```py
    with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as pipeline:
        messages = (
            pipeline
            | f"Read from input topic {subscription_id}" >>
            beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=subscription_id,
                                   with_attributes=False)
            | f"Deserialize Avro {subscription_id}" >> beam.ParDo(
                ConfluentAvroReader(schema_registry_conf)).with_outputs(
                    "record", "error"))

        records = messages["record"]
        errors = messages["error"]

        (records
         | 'Aggregate msgs in fixed window' >> beam.WindowInto(beam.window.FixedWindows(15))
         | 'Send hardcoded value to datadog' >> beam.ParDo(SendToDatadog())
         | 'Print results' >> beam.Map(print)
        )
```

Comment: The error occurs when you add values to a different data types, You can try using f string format to the line that error occurs.

Comment: That much is obvious but you'll see that the code throwing an error is deep within the beam sdk. I don't understand what the sdk harness is accomplishing and why one of those two values is populating as None. Tracing the values input source hasn't been fruitful

Comment: Is the graph being build in Dataflow, i.e. the pipeline starting at all?

Comment: @CaptainNabla Yes the pipeline graph is built and appears to run via the graphs displaying data freshness. No errors in the logs except for the Diagnostics tab that give the error above. I'll add a screenshot in a  moment

Comment: what exactly is your `SendToDatadog` doing with the windowing? Do you have custom code in there which is using the windowing information? Since you do not have any aggregation steps in your pipeline, the windowing is currently not applied (see [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#windowing-constraints))